# Какой слайдер-библиотека обычно используется в React?

Tags: reactjs, swiper

При верстке html-css-js для контента по типу изображений в основном используется swiper (имхо).
Какой слайдер в основном используется в реакте? Может тоже свайпер, или может вручную пишут?